# Sinatra and Rails - starting a submoduled app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, git-submodules

I've been basing an app with a blogging app (octopress) submoduled, on the following guide:

http://www.nickhammond.com/setting-octopress-jekyll-blog-rails-application/

It's a bit out of date but other than having to change around some gems seems to be working fine. The guide suggests having a folder called 'Blog' in your main parent app directory, in which the smaller app lives. Here I was told to change the config.ru file, and rename it to run.rb. The file is as follows:

/blog/run.rb

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra/base'

# The project root directory
$root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)

class Blog < Sinatra::Base

  get(/.+/) do
    send_sinatra_file(request.path) {404}
  end

  not_found do
    send_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public', '404.html'), {:status => 404})
  end

  def send_sinatra_file(path, &missing_file_block)
    file_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public',  path)
    file_path = File.join(file_path, 'index.html') unless file_path =~ /\.[a-z]+$/i
    File.exist?(file_path) ? send_file(file_path) : missing_file_block.call
  end

end
```

My config.ru file in my parent app is as follows:

/config.ru

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
require './blog/run'

# Action Cable requires that all classes are loaded in advance
Rails.application.eager_load!

map '/' do
  run Rails.application
end

map '/blog' do
    run Blog
end
```

When I visit localhost:3000/blog, I don't get a route not found error, however receive:

```
This localhost page can’t be found

No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:3000/blog
```

Any help on how to properly set up my config.ru file would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to move

```
require '/blog/run'


map '/blog' do
    run Blog
end
```

to the routes.rb and see if this helps.

Update: (at the end it said to change your config.ru to this).

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require './blog/run' # Require the run.rb file that we created earlier which has the Rack setup for the blog

map '/' do # By default we want everything to hit our Rails application
  run Rails::Application
end

map '/blog' do # Anything at blog/ and beyond will then hit the blog
  run Blog
end
```

Please give this a try.

Comment: Placing it inside the routes method gives an error:


    undefined method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fc101138728> (NoMethodError)

and outside the method gives a similar one too.

Comment: @Mark Please read my updated post and try this step and tell me if you get any errors.

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the time to try help. I've tried your suggestion, which is as far as I can see what I had it before minus the Rails.application.eager_load!, but when I try to nagivate to localhost:3000/blog I get the same error, No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:3000/blog